# function inside javascript loop

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble understanding this problem.  I'm assuming its a scope issue, but I don't know how to get around it.

I created an array to store the x and y positions of 6 separate elements

```
var pos = new Array();
for(i=1;i<7;i++){
    pos['box'+i] = $('.box'+i).position();
}
```

I would like to then add this to each element with another loop

```
for(i=1;i<7;i++){
    $('.box'+i).draggable({zIndex: 9999, revert: function(){
        $(this).animate({top:pos['box'+i].top, left:pos['box'+i].left}, 500, "easeOutElastic");
    }});
}
```

The dragging works, but the revert function doesn't.  With some alerts I found that it is trying to get the position of pos['box7'] which doesn't exist.  Why isn't it adding each 'box'+i ?

Comment: Ofcourse, this is the scope problem, since the internal "i" (i inside revert) is evaluated when draggable is executed and at that time its value is 7, it is not executed with loop since revert is not called then.

Comment: Tough to say what's going on exactly.  I would start by rearranging your selectors and animated objects to work with ids instead of classes.  Can include your markup as well?

Comment: Hello, revert is a boolean or string value, not a function. http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert

Comment: @Furqan You were right.  It made more sense to me when you explained it.  Before the animate function I added some code to grab $(this).position() and put it where needed in the animate function.  All is good now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to encapsulate the code inside the loop in a new "context":

```
(function(i) {
  .. your code
})(i);
```